# Any way of getting the repetition of a letter in an array?

Tags: python

So, here's my problem:

I need a way of counting the difference of equal letters in an array, if that wasn't clear enough, here is an example:
In: `estate`
Out: `+5 0 +2 0 0 0`
In: `tenant`
Out: `+5 0 +2 0 0 0`
**Explanation**
So, the +5 means that the 'e' is repeated 5 places later, 0 means that it isn't repeated **and** it also has to be the the same in 'tenant'.

I have this so far:

```
from collections import Counter
DEBUG = True
#############################################################
class Isomorph_Tools:
  def isIsomorphic(w1,w2) : 
    if len(w1) != len(w2): return False
    return [len(set(w1)),len(set(w2))] == 2 * [len(set(zip(w1,w2)))]


def get_len(a):
  counter=0
  for i in a:
    counter = counter + 1
  return counter

def do_1(ary,inx):
  for i in ary:
    no = 0
    for j in ary:
      for l in range(0,get_len(ary)):
        if ary.index(i) == inx and ary.index(i) != ary[l]:
          no+=1
          return no
        else:
          return 0

def main(a,b):
  words = [a.split(" "),b.split(" ")]
  if not(Isomorph_Tools.isIsomorphic(words[0],words[1])):
    print(words[0] + ', ' + words[1] + 'are not isomorphs')
    return
  else:
    lettersOne = list(words[0][0])
    print(lettersOne)
    lettersTwo = list(words[1][0])
    print(lettersTwo)
    the_ones = []
    ####Start The Calculation####
    for letter in lettersOne:
      letterIndex = lettersOne.index(letter)
      print(lettersOne.index(letter))
      for i in 
      the_ones.append(do_1(lettersOne,letterIndex))
      print(the_ones)

main('estate','tenant')
```

please help

Comment: Sorry, I *still* have *absolutely no idea* what you want the code to do. Why are there six numbers in the output for `estate tenant`? How do I know that the first one has to do with the letter `e`? Do you care about any non-letters, such as spaces? When you say " it also has to be the the same in 'tenant'.", what is "it"? What does it mean to "be the same in" another word?

Comment: It does look like you're making this **much** too hard for yourself, though. For example, the `get_len` that you've written is **built-in** (i.e. you don't even have to import anything yourself), and just called `len`.

Comment: e s t a t e
^         ^
These two e's are 5 characters apart

I made them into an array
['e', 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'e']
and i need to find how far apart the e's are

['t', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'n', 't']
The same pattern takes place in tenant
the t's are 5 apart and the n's are 2 apart

Comment: len() didn't work :/

Comment: What do you mean `len() didn't work`? You're already using it in `isIsomorphic`!

Comment: welp. i used it wrong. I used it as .len() like the Ruby .length

Comment: @opo, I just edited your expected outputs for clarity. Please ping me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep! right! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to find how far the next repeated element is from current element.

Here is one way you could do:

```
s = 'estate'

print([next((j for j, x in enumerate(s[i+1:], 1) if s[i] == x), 0) for i in range(len(s))])
# [5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

For `'tenant'` also, it outputs `[5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]`.
Forget about signs, it's anyway positive.

Comment: how would I remove the []'s though?

Comment: @opo use a `*`. `print(*[next(...`

Comment: @opo, `', '.join(lst)`, where `lst` is the output above.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
text = 'estate tenant'                                                          
words = text.split(' ') # Split up the words                                    
out = []                                                                        
for word in words:                                                              
    part = [word.find(char, i+1)-i for i,char in enumerate(word)]               
    out.append([max(index,0) for index in part])
```